# Web scraped with Selenium content not correctly updating after selecting another language

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website using Selenium to build a corpus in different languages. As trial, at first I am trying to scrape from only one webpage. I want to get the text from a native language and collect its translation. When I run everything manually line by line it works, as I get "fre" for "french" ("flansegbe" in native language) body text and "fon" body text in correct languages.
But when I try to run everything directly from my file I just get the same content in only one language, here fon language. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

g =r'C:\\Users\\romeo\\OneDrive\\Documents\\ELU\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = g)

driver.get("https://www.jw.org/fon/nus%C9%9Bxwet%C9%9Bn/xojlawema-l%C9%9B/at%C9%94xw%C9%9B-aluunsun-2016-t%C9%94n-t%C9%94n/nu-e-wu-m%C9%9B-l%C9%9B-n%C9%94-%C9%96o-adingban-e/")

fon = []
fre = []

elefon = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pGroup']")

fon.append(elefon.text)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='jsAutoComplete jsShowFeatured jsAutoCompleteInput autoCompleteLanguageChoices']")

inputElement.send_keys('Flansegbe')

inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#elefre = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pGroup']")
#fre.append(elefre.text)

fon

fre
```

Comment: you need to 'pause' the progrm and let the pages load. usually thia is done with `time.sleep()` pr with selenium `Waits`

Comment: Oh ok great, and thanks for replying. I tried with time.sleep(10) but not everytime sucessful. Should I increase waiting time ?

Comment: hmm 10 seconds should be fine if you have a good internet connection. I don't know which might be the problem at this point.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and it worked fine. I just only have to see how to cope with access denied after 200 pages, (I suppose) I am firing too much request so i think my IP is being blocked  :D